# Cannot get items from AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I am trying to query the user data that I have saved locally in the device and use it to make an API call.
The problem is that when I do it 75% of the time AsyncStorage returns null for the user, but 25% of the time i can query the user i dont know what the problem is.

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  function getQuote() {
    var retrieveData = async () => {
      try {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("user");
        const data = JSON.parse(value);
        setUser(data.user.email);
      } catch (error) {}
    };
    retrieveData();

    fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/order/", {
      method: "POST",
      body:
        "product_id=" +
        product._id +
        "&user=" +
        user +
        "&quantity=" +
        quote +
        "&status=Request",
      headers: { "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        var message = "";
        if (responseJson.result === true) {
          message =
            "Your request for the quote has been made. You will recieve a quote in the quotes tab shortly.";
        } else {
          message =
            "There was an error while send the request. Please try again in a short while.";
        }
        
      });
  }
```

I have also tried doing

```
while(user === null){
retrieveData();
}
```

But this just makes my app crash.

Answer (score 1):

You have to also use async/await while calling retrieveData function.
I have modified your code. Now it works correctly

```html
const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  async function getQuote() {
    var retrieveData = async () => {
      try {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("user");
        const data = JSON.parse(value);
        setUser(data.user.email);
      } catch (error) {}
    };
    await retrieveData();

    fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/order/", {
      method: "POST",
      body:
        "product_id=" +
        product._id +
        "&user=" +
        user +
        "&quantity=" +
        quote +
        "&status=Request",
      headers: { "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        var message = "";
        if (responseJson.result === true) {
          message =
            "Your request for the quote has been made. You will recieve a quote in the quotes tab shortly.";
        } else {
          message =
            "There was an error while send the request. Please try again in a short while.";
        }
        
      });
  }
```